# Issues with For and MailApp

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code that I have compiled from some other codes but it is not doing quite what I want.  The idea is to cycle through each row searching for a keyword (TRUE) and send an email to the email address listed in column A with the message in column B.  Unfortunately, I'm not skilled enough to work this through myself.

```
function findAndSendMail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Reminder');
  var search = "TRUE"
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var range = ss.getRange(1,5,lastRow); //define range for column E
  //find all occurrences of "TRUE" in column E and push range to array
  var ranges = range.createTextFinder(search).findAll();
  var message = '';

  //loop through each range
  for (i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {

    var row = ranges[i].getRow();
    var lastCol = ss.getLastColumn();
    var values = ss.getRange(row, 1, 1, lastCol).getValues(); //get all values for the row
    var emailAddress = values[0][0];       //column A
    var reminder = values[0][1]; //column B
    var sendvalidation = values[0][4]; //column E

    if (sendvalidation = true) {
      message+=Utilities.formatString("**This is an automated message.**\n\n"+reminder+"\n\n**This is an automated message.**");
    }

  var subject = 'General Reminder';

  if (message) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
}
```

I want one email for each row with only the information from that row.  What I am currently getting is one email with the first row, then another email with the first and second row, then another email with the first, second and third row, etc.

Comment: This `if (sendvalidation = true) {` should be this `if (sendvalidation == true) {` or just this `if (sendvalidation) {`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the question, it sounds like you have a spreadsheet and you want it to send the content in col B to the recipient in col A if col E = "TRUE". I'm a bit of a novice myself, but here is how I would approach this situation. What we're doing here is pulling all the data in the spreadsheet into an array, then looping over that array pushing rows into a new array if col E = "TRUE." We then loop over the new array, and send an email for each row with its data.

```
`function findAndSendMail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Reminder');
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var emails = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i ++) {
   //  Make sure this points at the column you want to check 
    if(data[i][4] === "TRUE") {
      emails.push(data[i]);
    }
  }
  for(var j = 0; j < emails.length; j ++) {
    var row = emails[j];
    var emailAddress = row[0];
    var reminder = row[1];
    if(reminder !== "") {
      var message = "**This is an automated message.**\n\n"" + reminder + "\n\n**This 
is an automated message.**";
      var email = {
        to: emailAddress,
        subject: "General Reminder",
        body: message
        };
      MailApp.sendEmail(email);
    } 
  }
 } `
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out on my own.  The code I stole from was set up differently, so I was able to get it to work by removing some conditionals.

```
function findAndSendMail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Reminder');
  var search = "TRUE"
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var range = ss.getRange(1,5,lastRow); //define range for column E
  //find all occurrences of "TRUE" in column E and push range to array
  var ranges = range.createTextFinder(search).findAll();

  //loop through each range
  for (i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {

    var row = ranges[i].getRow();
    var lastCol = ss.getLastColumn();
    var values = ss.getRange(row, 1, 1, lastCol).getValues(); //get all values for the row
    var emailAddress = values[0][0];       //column A
    var reminder = values[0][1]; //column B
    var sendvalidation = values[0][4]; //column E

    var message = reminder;
    var subject = 'General Reminder';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, "**This is an automated message.**\n\n"+message+"\n\n**This is an automated message.**");
  }
}
```